# Store article's image in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing a MERN application and there is an article component that has some text fields and one preview image. I need to store this data in MongoDB. I've tried to use multer, but there is a problem with loading image. When I use fetch to post an image on my route, there is an error 404. How can this image be properly posted and got from my DB? There are some pieces of my code:

**Article Component's JSX**:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Form extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  storeImg(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const file = document.getElementById('previewImageInput').files;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('img', file[0]);
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/images", { // returns an error 404
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .then(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/images/${file[0].name}`)
          .then((res) => console.log(res.data));
      })
  }

  render() {   
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          id="imageFile"
          type="file"
        />
        <button onClick={this.storeImage}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Images route**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");
const crypto = require('crypto');
const cors = require("cors");
const GridFsStorage = require("multer-gridfs-storage");
const Grid = require("gridfs-stream");

const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const router = require('express').Router();

const conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/db-name');

let gfs;

conn.once("open", () => {
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection("uploads");
  console.log("Connection Successful");
});

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: 'mongodb://localhost/db-name',
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = file.originalname;
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: "uploads"
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

router.post("/", upload.single("img"), (req, res, err) => {
  res.send(req.files);
});

router.get("/:filename", (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename }, (err, file) => {
    if (!file || file.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: "No file exists"
      });
    }

    if (file.contentType === "image/jpeg" || file.contentType === "image/png") {
      const readstream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename);
      readstream.pipe(res);
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({
        err: "Not an image"
      });
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this. I would create an folder called for example `multerMiddlewares`. It contains for the beginning 1 File called `articlePictureUpload.js`

It looks like this:

```
module.exports =  function(req, res) {
  const multer = require("multer");
  const fs = require("fs");
  let user;


  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      user = "5da4ksfgd4ds"; //this should be unique, this could be the _id that is stored in the mongo database
      const dir = `./static/uploads/${user}/article`;
      if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {  //checks if directory exist, if not it will create one
        fs.mkdirSync(dir, { recursive: true });
      }
      return cb(null, dir);
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      let name = Date.now();
      cb(null, `${name}.jpeg`);  //
    }
  });
  const upload = multer({ storage });

  return upload;
}
```

Now we are done with the multer middleware, now you can use it:

First import it:

```
const articleUploadMiddleware = require("path/to/multer/middleware");

router.post('/', articleUploadMiddleware().single("image") ,(req, res, next) => {

   //some code....
   let filePath = req.file.path; //save this path into your database
   //more code

}
```

On your client, i guess you using axios, its important to set the headers to `multipart/form-data` and send your request like this:

You need an event listener on change on the file input `<input typ="file" />` that triggers a function, for example `uploadImg`

```
uploadImg(e){
   const articleImg = e.target.files[0];
   let formData = new FormData();
   formData.append("image", articleImg);
   axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "yourUrl",
      data: formData,
      headers: {
         "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      }
   })
}
```

At this point, if everything success, your img should be stored in the directory `./static/uploads/5da4ksfgd4ds/article/12412334234.jpg`. The big number is the timestamp. You can named it however you want.

And the path to this img should be stored in the db

Comment: I used `axios` instead of `fetch` like in your example code and everything worked.

Comment: @anDev ofocrse you can append some other data on `formData.append()` and access it with `req.body`